# Function with nested WHILE loop producing unexpected results

Tags: python, list, loops, while-loop, fibonacci

I am learning python in college, and have been having trouble with some concepts, mainly loops. I need help understanding why my code is producing an incorrect result:

```
def fibonacci(maxint):
    a, b = 0, 1
    LIST = [a, b]
    while b < maxint:
        a, b = b, a + b
        LIST.append(b)
    return LIST
```

In order to test the script, I need to call the function and pass 10 as an argument in the console:

```
>>>fibonacci(10)
```

The output should show as:

```
[0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8]
```

but it is actually printing:

```
[0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13]
```

Can someone please analyze my code and tell me the following:

1. where is it inefficient?
2. Why is it going out of bounds and looping past 10 (the argument from my function)?

Comment: Because you test on `b < maxint`, then *update* `b` (which can go out of bounds) and finally append the updated one...

Comment: Furthermore what should happen if you call `fibonacci(0)`. In that case I would expect an empty list?

Comment: What makes you think the code's inefficient?

Comment: What's a nested while loop? In your terminology, what would a non-nested while loop look like?

Comment: It is helpful to actually work through the logic of your while-loops with pencil and paper for small examples. It should become clear why it is always appending the first value past `maxint`

Comment: My teacher will test the code by typing "fibonacci(10)" into the console (after importing the module). He will expect to see [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8], not [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13]. I think I cheated because I set the initial value of LIST to [0, 1], but I don't think this is efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, Your code is **not inefficient** as it is an **iterative** approach for generating Fibonacci numbers.

Secondly, the following code will rectify the problem with your code regarding values appending beyond `maxint` :

```
def fibonacci(maxint):
    a, b = 0, 1
    LIST = [a]
    while b < maxint:
        LIST.append(b) # appending the b's value to the list before it is updated.
        a, b = b, a + b
    return LIST
```

Your code was printing **'13'** because you are appending the value of **'b'** into the list after it's value is changed to **'13'**. So, in the last loop when value of **'b = 8'**, the new updated value will be **'b=13'**.

```
>>>fibonacci(10)
>>>[0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8]
```

Comment: What was the code's problem and why does this rectify it?